# The array Within My json, looks like string and not json

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoskin

I am new to js node. Rest my service registration API worked fine until i HAD to Incorporate an array to json. Now the array mongo saves it as a string and displays it as a string like string. I think that something is missing or wrong API, but perhaps it is the client and sending the data. please help. (sorry for my english).
My code...

```
app.post('/event', function(req, res){

var startDateArray = req.body.datestart.split("-");
var endDateArray = req.body.dateend.split("-");
var startDateDate = new Date(startDateArray[0],startDateArray[1] - 1, startDateArray[2]);
var endDateDate = new Date(endDateArray[0],endDateArray[1] - 1, endDateArray[2]);
req.body.datestart = startDateDate;
req.body.dateend = endDateDate;


  db.collection("conferences").insert(req.body,function(e, result){
    res.send(result);
  });
});
```

My client in angularjs

```
//initialization object that stores the input of sight
$scope.registroEvento = {
    name: '',
    address: '',
    city: '',
    organizer: '',
    country: '',
    lat: '',
    lon: '',
    distance: '',
    datestart: '',
    dateend: '',
    timestart: '',
    timeend: '',
    description: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    web: '',
    price: '',
    buylink: '',
    image: '',
    category: '',
    ticket: []
};

//An entry is added by the condition (free or paid)
$scope.agregarEntrada = function (condicion) {
    $scope.registroEvento.ticket.push({
        nombre: '',
        cantidad: '',
        precio: '',
        esGratis: condicion ? true : false,
        descripcion: '',
        muestraDescripcion: false //atributo que maneja la descripcion (show-hide)
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.registroEvento.ticket));
};
//API response
{
"_id": "55afff616e2ce6e8044cb772",
"name": "Evento",
"address": "",
"city": "Temuco",
"country": "Chile",
"lat": "-33.44888975",
"lon": "-70.6692655",
"distance": "",
"datestart": "2015-07-31T04:00:00.000Z",
"dateend": "2015-07-31T04:00:00.000Z",
"timestart": "22:22",
"timeend": "22:02",
"category": "",
"ticket[ticket][0][nombre]": "galeria",
"ticket[ticket][0][cantidad]": "11",
"ticket[ticket][0][precio]": "",
"ticket[ticket][0][esGratis]": "true",
"ticket[ticket][0][descripcion]": "descripcion",
"ticket[ticket][0][muestraDescripcion]": "true",
"ticket[ticket][0][$$hashKey]": "object:7",
"dateParse": "Friday, July 31, 2015",
"ticket[ticket][1][nombre]": "galeria",
"ticket[ticket][1][cantidad]": "100",
"ticket[ticket][1][precio]": "1000",
"ticket[ticket][1][esGratis]": "false",
"ticket[ticket][1][descripcion]": "descripcion",
"ticket[ticket][1][muestraDescripcion]": "true",
"ticket[ticket][1][$$hashKey]": "object:8",
"dateParse": "Friday, July 31, 2015"
}
```

Comment: So the response you show should come in JSON?

Comment: yes, i need send and save an array, but I dont know how send the object from angular to nodejs with this problem and save it in mongo